# Perl: extract rows from 1 to n (Windows)

Tags: perl, csv

I want to extract rows 1 to n from my .csv file. Using this

```
perl -ne 'if ($. == 3) {print;exit}' infile.txt
```

I can extract only one row. How to put a range of rows into this script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write from n-th row to a file using perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365053/how-to-write-from-n-th-row-to-a-file-using-perl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
head -3 infile.txt
```

If you really must use Perl then this works:

```
perl -ne 'if ($. <= 3) {print} else {exit}' infile.txt
```

Comment: I assume the problem with `head` is working on Windows without cygwin.

Comment: `perl -wpe'1..3 or exit' infile.txt`

Comment: @ysth the point of my example was not to write the most abbreviated Perl possible but to show a more generic example of conditional processing based on line number.

Comment: so ysth shows you "the most generic way of conditional processing based on line number".

Comment: no, mine shows how to "do a, or do b".  His is "print, or exit".

Answer (score 11):

If you have only a single range and a single, possibly concatenated input stream, you can use:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
if (my $seqno = 1 .. 3) {
    print;
    exit if $seqno =~ /E/;
}
```

But if you want it to apply to each input file, you need to catch the end of each file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
print if my $seqno = 1 .. 3;
close ARGV if eof || $seqno =~ /E/;
```

And if you want to be kind to people who forget args, add a nice warning in a `BEGIN` or `INIT` clause:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
BEGIN { warn "$0: reading from stdin\n" if @ARGV == 0 && -t }
print if my $seqno = 1 .. 3;
close ARGV if eof || $seqno =~ /E/;
```

Notable points include:

- You can use `-n` or `-p` on the `#!` line. You could also put some (but *not* all) other [command line switches](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) there, like `‑l` or `‑a`.
- Numeric literals as
  operands to the scalar flip‐flop
  operator are each compared against
  `readline` counter, so a scalar `1 ..
  3` is really `($. == 1) .. ($. ==
  3)`.
- Calling `eof` with neither an argument **nor empty parens** means the last file read in the *magic `ARGV`* list of files.  This contrasts with `eof()`, which is the end of the *entire* `<ARGV>` iteration.
- A flip‐flop operator’s final sequence number is returned with a `"E0"` appended to it.
- The `-t` operator, which calls libc’s `isatty(3)`, default to the `STDIN` handle — unlike any of the other filetest operators.
- A `BEGIN{}` block happens during compilation, so if you try to decompile this script with `‑MO=Deparse` to see what it really does, that check will execute.  With an `INIT{}`, it will not.
- Doing just that will reveal that the implicit input loop as a label called `LINE` that you perhaps might in other circumstances use to your advantage.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

You can use the range operator:

```
perl -ne 'if (1 .. 3) { print } else { last }' infile.txt
```