# flip-flop-operator/readline-counter question

Tags: perl, counter, readline, flip-flop

Reading this [Perl: extract rows from 1 to n (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069243/perl-extract-rows-from-1-to-n-windows) I didn't understand the flip-flop-operator/readline-counter part.

```
perl -nE 'say $c if $c=1..3' my_file
```

> 1
>   2
>   3E0

Could someone explain me more detailed where this output comes from?

Comment: See [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) under 'Range Operators'. It is also discussed at length in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365053/how-to-write-from-n-th-row-to-a-file-using-perl/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

> In scalar context, "`..`" returns a
>   boolean value. The operator is
>   bistable, like a flip-flop, and
>   emulates the line-range (comma)
>   operator of **sed**, **awk**, and various
>   editors. Each "`..`" operator maintains
>   its own boolean state, even across
>   calls to a subroutine that contains
>   it. It is false as long as its left
>   operand is false. Once the left
>   operand is true, the range operator
>   stays true until the right operand is
>   true, AFTER which the range operator
>   becomes false again. It doesn't become
>   false till the next time the range
>   operator is evaluated. It can test the
>   right operand and become false on the
>   same evaluation it became true (as in
>   **awk**), but it still returns true once.
>   If you don't want it to test the right
>   operand until the next evaluation, as
>   in **sed**, just use three dots ("`...`")
>   instead of two. In all other regards,
>   "`...`" behaves just like "`..`" does.
>
> The right operand is not evaluated
>   while the operator is in the "false"
>   state, and the left operand is not
>   evaluated while the operator is in the
>   "true" state. The precedence is a
>   little lower than `||` and `&&`. The value
>   returned is either the empty string
>   for false, or a sequence number
>   (beginning with 1) for true. The
>   sequence number is reset for each
>   range encountered. ***The final sequence
>   number in a range has the string "E0"
>   appended to it***, which doesn't affect
>   its numeric value, but gives you
>   something to search for if you want to
>   exclude the endpoint. You can exclude
>   the beginning point by waiting for the
>   sequence number to be greater than 1.
>
> If either operand of scalar "`..`" is a
>   constant expression, that operand is
>   considered true if it is equal (`==`)
>   to the current input line number (the
>   `$.` variable).

(emphasis added)